# Join in LINQ with DefaultIfEmpty still causing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it really possible to cause a `NullReferenceException` on a join statement even if it has the `DefaultIfEmpty()` code?

```
     var getWorkerList = (from a in workerList
                         join ps in db.ProjectStatus on a.StatusId equals ps.StatusId into hjps
                         from ps in hjps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join psc in db.StatusColor on ps.StatusCode equals psc.StatusCode into hjpsc
                         from psc in hjpsc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join lu in db.LOOKUPS on psc.StatusColorID equals lu.LOOKUPS_ID into hjlu
                         from lu in hjlu.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new WorkerModel()
                         {
                            FullName = a.FullName
                            ,Color = lu.LOOKUPS_Code                  
                         }).OrderBy(a => a.WorkerId).ToList();
```

Here is where I get the `NullReferenceException` Error :

```
join lu in db.LOOKUPS on psc.StatusColorID equals lu.LOOKUPS_ID into hjlu
                         from lu in hjlu.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

When adding this join statement I get the error. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.DefaultIfEmpty()` returns a sequence with a single default value **if the original source is empty**.

It will still throw a null reference exception, **if the original source is null**.

Comment: so sir where do you think is the faulty join ?

Comment: There is no way for me to know which of your variables have which value (I mean just imagine I could tell you what happens in your computers RAM remotely, wouldn't that be scary? :) ). Try to produce a [MCVE] and you will probably find it.

Comment: Heres the scenario, if i removed the line for Lookups, its not causing errors but when added theres where it shows. I also tried removing the `,Color = lu.LOOKUPS_Code` but to no avail still shows `null reference`

Answer (score 1):

you are using 'left join' instead of 'join' by '.DefaultIfEmpty()'

so you have to correct select statement: replace 'Color = lu.LOOKUPS_Code' with this: 'Color = lu == null ? "" : lu.LOOKUPS_Code'.

also you are able to use a different overload of '.DefaultIfEmpty()' to set a replacement instead of 'null', so then the select statement wouldn't throw an exception

Comment: I also tried removing the statement ` ,Color = lu.LOOKUPS_Code  ` but the error still occurs

Comment: strange... are you sure , you're getting exactly 'null reference' after removing ` ,Color = lu.LOOKUPS_Code ` ? if you are getting 'null reference' after removing that line of the code, the exception has not something to do with your query statement and probably originates from somewhere else